# how can i remove jquery conflict when they are called on same page due to function over writing...?

Tags: jquery, function, overriding, conflict, overwrite

i m a beginner...
i have added two different jQuery... one is pop up which calls a file(ajax) and another is slider on the page...?

i have tried the "jQuery.noConflict();" but they only work for two different libraries ...?

here i m using only jQuery....

here is the code...

```
<script>
    /* calls the pop-up */
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".example5").colorbox();
    });
    /* calls the slider */
        $(function(){
        $('.selecter').mobilyselect({
            collection: 'all',
            animation: 'absolute',
            duration: 500,
            listClass: 'selecterContent',
            btnsClass: 'selecterBtns',
            btnActiveClass: 'active',
            elements: 'li',
            onChange: function(){},
            onComplete: function(){}
        });
    });

</script>
```

`

when i remove one calling function the other called script works....
but when i keep both... the last called one works....

may be this is due to function over writing... but i don't know how to solve it...?

thanking you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine the two:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".example5").colorbox();

    $('.selecter').mobilyselect({
        collection: 'all',
        animation: 'absolute',
        duration: 500,
        listClass: 'selecterContent',
        btnsClass: 'selecterBtns',
        btnActiveClass: 'active',
        elements: 'li',
        onChange: function(){},
        onComplete: function(){}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just put them in the same function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".example5").colorbox();

        $('.selecter').mobilyselect({
            collection: 'all',
            animation: 'absolute',
            duration: 500,
            listClass: 'selecterContent',
            btnsClass: 'selecterBtns',
            btnActiveClass: 'active',
            elements: 'li',
            onChange: function(){},
            onComplete: function(){}
        });
});
```

Is there some reason you can't do this?

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to remove the entire `$(function(){` section and only have the code above inside of your script tags.  Is that what you tried?

Comment: i tried the same code you gave...

these scripts calls the file
for pop up
<script src="javascripts/popup-jquery/jquery.popup.googleapis.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/popup-jquery/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
for the slider
<script src="slide/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="slide/js/mobilyselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
may be this might give you more idea...
thank you

Comment: The comment you just left is nearly unreadable. What you have posted is better suited as an update to your question.  In addition to that you should post any relevant js.  Just posting the name of the js file is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.noConflict()` is used for when two different libraries want control over `$` (like, say, jQuery and Prototype...or even two different versions of jQuery if you want that for some bizarre reason).  It's not needed when you just have two different scripts that *use* jQuery; in fact, `jQuery.noConflict()` makes it so that `$` doesn't mean `jQuery` anymore, and will usually break any script that expects to be able to use `$` (as both of your event handlers do).  jQuery will chain handlers together so one runs after the other without your having to do much else.

Both scripts should work if you remove the `jQuery.noConflict()`.  Or, as mentioned by others, combine the two into one handler.  They don't really need to be separate anyway.  But still, both should work fine, if (1) your syntax is correct, (2) the plugins are loaded and (3) you're using them correctly.  See http://jsfiddle.net/BeRLB/ for an example of two event handlers cooperating just fine.

If you are actually using two different `$` libraries, then it only gets a tiny bit more complicated.  In order to continue using `$`, you'd have to wrap your code in a function that you pass jQuery to, like so...

```
(function($) {
     $(function() { ... });
     $(document).ready(function() { ... });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: here i m using only jquery....
no mootools, no prototype...
 thought i have already tried this... but again it is not working...
thank you...

Comment: Then chances are, one of your plugin calls is throwing an error.  Check your JS console.  This should work just fine, if the syntax is right and you're using the plugins correctly.  But if the first part is throwing an error, the second part will not run.

Comment: thank you....
i checked my console... when i use any one these function they are working... without error... but when i use both of them... it shows error like.... object uncaught...

Comment: "object uncaught"?  That doesn't sound right.  What *exactly* does the error say?

Comment: the error says 
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'colorbox'
when the code is as mention in my question...

Comment: the added js file are.....
<script src="javascripts/popup-jquery/jquery.popup.googleapis.js"></script>                                                        
<script src="javascripts/popup-jquery/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script src="slide/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="slide/js/mobilyselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
....

Comment: That usually means one of two things: either the colorbox plugin isn't loaded at the time you're trying to use it, or `$` isn't jQuery anymore.  The latter is caused by someone calling `jQuery.noConflict()` or loading another JS library that hijacks `$` (which you're claiming isn't the case for you).  That just leaves the colorbox script not being loaded.

Comment: Wait one minute.  You're loading plugins before you even load jQuery?  That ain't gonna work.  Switch the scripts so jquery loads first, *then* the plugins.

Comment: ok..... thank you...

yes... i tried switching the scripts but now the error shown is....Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mobilyselect'

Comment: I meant switch the `<script>` elements so that jquery.js is the first one, and the plugins are after it, and your script comes after all that.  Scripts load and run in order the script tags appear in the document.  If the plugins load before jQuery does, then there's no jQuery for them to attach to -- and once jQuery finally does get loaded, those plugins aren't there anymore (if they were ever there in the first place).

Comment: OMG....
I tried copying the code of the mobilyselect into the colorbox
and changed the code to 

`<script>
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
   $(".example5").colorbox();
  });
  
  $(function(){
   $('.selecter').mobilyselect({
    collection: 'all',
    animation: 'absolute',
    duration: 500,
    listClass: 'selecterContent',
    btnsClass: 'selecterBtns',
    btnActiveClass: 'active',
    elements: 'li',
    onChange: function(){},
    onComplete: function(){}
   });
  });

 </script>`

and yes... it worked....
i m very very thankful for you help
regards...

Answer (score 0):

You can call multiple jQuery functions inside the `$(document).ready(function(){});` function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".example5").colorbox();

        $('.selecter').mobilyselect({
            collection: 'all',
            animation: 'absolute',
            duration: 500,
            listClass: 'selecterContent',
            btnsClass: 'selecterBtns',
            btnActiveClass: 'active',
            elements: 'li',
            onChange: function(){},
            onComplete: function(){}
        });
});
```